# Javascript Yield Calculator that emulates Excel

Tags: javascript, excel

I am building a bond calculator and I need to get the Yield outputted as a percentage I have used Excel as a guide and the `=YIELD()` function that is in there.

In excel for these given values I return `5.181800`

```
=YIELD(19-02-2015, 21-02-2019, 5.75/100, 102.031, 100, 2, 1)*100
=YIELD(SettlementDate, MaturityDate, CouponsRate, BondPrice, 100, Coupons PA, Basis) * 100
```

In Javascript I have written

```
function dayDiff(date1, date2) {

    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 

    return diffDays;
}

var settlement = '2015-02-19',
maturity = '2019-02-21',

settlement = new Date(settlement);
maturity = new Date(maturity);

var timeToMaturity = dayDiff(settlement, maturity);
var coupon = 5.75 / 100;
var yield = 102.031;
var redemption = 100;
var frequency = 2;

var price = 0.0;
if(timeToMaturity > 0) {
    price += redemption;
}
var paymentTime = timeToMaturity;
while(paymentTime > 0) {
    price += coupon/frequency;

    // Discount back
    price = price / (1.0 + yield / frequency);
    paymentTime -= 1.0 / frequency;
}
var accrualPeriod = 0.0-paymentTime;
price *= Math.pow(1.0 + yield / frequency, accrualPeriod*frequency);
price -= coupon/frequency * accrualPeriod*frequency;

console.log(price * 100 * 100);
```

This returns `5.635542139153786` can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Pasting your Excel formula into Excel, I get a #NUM error.  Are you sure that is the formula you are using?  Also, if that is the formula you are using, Excel is NOT interpreting your dates as dates; rather as a mathematical formula.

Comment: The Excel formula is pulling from other cell values but I thought it best to show the variables involved.

Comment: Check if your formula is the same as described here [https://support.office.com/en-us/article/YIELD-function-896a73c6-f1a5-46df-a367-c197d8115b89?CorrelationId=33e95c5b-341c-40d4-a688-2a5cc7e52ed2&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/YIELD-function-896a73c6-f1a5-46df-a367-c197d8115b89?CorrelationId=33e95c5b-341c-40d4-a688-2a5cc7e52ed2&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: Thats where I got the Excel portion from so yes all is well there

Comment: @JustinErswell OK, then they are probably OK, except I think your maturity date, as you wrote it in the Excel `YIELD` formula, is incorrect -- the year should probably be `2019`, not `2015`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that one out any thoughts on why the JavaScript is returning a different result

Comment: @JustinErswell From your results, it seems your Java is calculating current yield   `5.75% * 100 / 102.031`  so there's something wrong with your time calculations.  Excel's `YIELD` function calculates Yield to Maturity